# Copying files in SAS

Tags: sas

I have been trying to get this code to work...but no luck so far:

```
%let drive=I:;
%let dir1=%nrbquote("AB&C\Reports & Tests\ABC\My Codes\01Jan12");
%let dir2=%nrbquote("AB&C\Reports & Tests\Test ABC\01 - Jan 2012\Test Code");

%sysExec &drive move "&dir1\Code_to_Move.sas" "&dir2" /y ;
```

I get the error message "system cannot find the path specified" in the command prompt. I think it is due to the spaces and the "&" in the folder names but I cannot seem to fix it.

Basically trying to copy over a file from one folder to another. Files are located on a network drive "I".

Can you please suggest the best way to do this using the directory structure I posted?

Comment: have you executed %sysexec I: move "AB&C\Reports & Tests\ABC\My Codes\01Jan12\code_to_move.sas" "AB&C\Reports & Tests\Test ABC\01 - Jan 2012\Test Code" /y successfully?

Answer (score 1):

> %let dir1=%nrbquote(AB&C\Reports & Tests\ABC\My Codes\01Jan12);

not

> %let dir1=%nrbquote("AB&C\Reports & Tests\ABC\My Codes\01Jan12");

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a period after &dir1 (I know you need a period after the macro var reference since it is followed by a /, not sure if other things are wrong also)

Comment: Did not work. I tried adding the period after all macros and only drive but still the same error

Comment: Found the problem! the position of the drive macro was wrong... should be - %sysExec move "&drive.\&dir1\Code_to_Move.sas" "&drive.\&dir2";